# What did Ferrari ask in Italian from "Luigi" & "Guido"?

Tags: dialogue, cars

In *Cars* (2006), at the end of the movie some Ferrari arrive at Luigi's tire shop, then the Ferrari ask something from Luigi in Italian. then Luigi fainted, the Ferrari again ask something from Guido, he also fainted.

What did the Ferrari ask from "Luigi" & "Guido" in Italian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to Michael Schumacker Ferrari...

The conversation goes...

> Michael Schumacker: Ciao! Hi, Lightning McQueen told me this was the best place in the world to get tires. How 'bout setting me and my friends up with three or four sets each?
>
> Luigi: Huh. Guido! There is a real Michael Schumacker Ferrari in my store. A real Ferrari! Punch me, Guido. Punch me in the face. This is the most glorious day of my life.
>
> Michael Schumacker: **Wow. Spero che il tuo amico si riprenda. Mi dicono che siete fantastici.**

Which translates to...

> **Wow. I hope your friend will recover. They tell me you're fantastic.**